# If $f'$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ then $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n+1$

Tags: derivatives, polynomials

I have the following problem but I don't know how to solve it.

> Use the mean value theorem to show that if $f$ is differentiable and $f'$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ then $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n+1$.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Do you really need to use the mean value theorem? The result is easy to prove without it.

Comment: Yes. I must use the mean value theorem.

Comment: By mean value theorem, do you mean Lagrange's mean value theorem? Because, Taylor's mean value theorem would, for example, directly give the result.

Comment: @Ennar Yes, I mean Lagrange's mean value theorem.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $f(x) - f(0) = \displaystyle \int_{0}^x f'(t)dt$

Comment: I do not understand how to solve the problem through this hint. Could you give me a full solution?

Comment: This is hardly mean value theorem, which is explicitly stated in the question. Although, by far the simplest method.

Comment: @Ennar any idea how to do this problem using mean value theorem?

Comment: @zeeks, well, not really, unfortunately. If you try to apply it for some $x$, you get that there is $\alpha$ such that $f(x) - f(0) = f'(x-\alpha)\cdot x$. Now this might seem like it's done, but $\alpha$ depends on $x$ and there is still to prove that for any $y$ one would have $f(y) - f(0) = f'(y-\alpha)\cdot y$. But, if you could show that $g(y) = f(y) - f(0) - f'(y-\alpha)\cdot y$ is constant, that would be it.

Comment: @zeeks, I don't think this will work, though.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be a differentiable function such that $f'(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$. Define $P(x):=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} {f^{(k)}(0)\over k!}x^k$, where $f^{(k)}$ is the $k^{\rm th}$ derivative of $f$ ($f^{(0)}=f$), and $g(x):=f(x)-P(x)$. It is easy to check that $g^{(k)}(0)=0$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,n+1$. Also, $g^{(k)}$ is a polynomial of degree $n+1-k$ for $1,2,\ldots,n+1$.

Because $g^{(n+1)}$ is a polynomial of degree $0$ (i.e. a constant function) and $g^{(n+1)}(0)=0$, we have $g^{(n+1)}(x)=0$ for all $x$. Consequently, fixing $x$ for a moment, by the Mean Value Theorem there is a number $\xi$ between $x$ and $0$ such that  $g^{(n)}(x)=g^{(n)}(x)-g^{(n)}(0)=g^{(n+1)}(\xi)\cdot(x-0)=0\cdot x =0$. Thus, $g^{(n)}(x)=0$ for all $x$. Successive applications of MVT show in turn that $g^{(k)}(x)=0$ for all $x$, for $k=n-1,n-2,\ldots,1,0$. The final conclusion is that $g^{(0)}(x)=g(x)=0$ for all $x$. That is, $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1} {f^{(k)}(0)\over k!}x^k$, so that $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n+1$.